# wal_level < logical error while upgrading aurora postgres db

Tags: amazon-aurora

I am trying to upgrade aurora postgres 10.11 to aurora postgres 11.9 in aws RDS aurora Postgres instance. The upgrade worked on test env, but the it gives following error on actual env

> logical replication slot "replication_slot" exists, but wal_level < logical

When I checked the system settings from pg_settings, its showing that the setting "wal_level" has value "logical". and rds.logical_replication is set to 1

this query returns below results

```
select name, setting, sourcefile, sourceline from pg_settings where name = 'wal_level';

name     |setting|sourcefile|sourceline|
---------+-------+----------+----------+
wal_level|logical|          |          |
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.PostgreSQL.html

as per the above doc

**Aurora DB clusters that are configured as logical replication publishers or subscribers can't undergo a major version upgrade [1].**

we must drop replication slots before the upgrade and set rds.logical_replication to 0 (default) in the cluster parameter group so that a major version upgrade can go through.

and recreate the replication slots if needed.